# Microsoft Graph - Issue with empty SharePoint ChoiceField

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting an unexpected response when calling

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/SomeList?$expand=items($expand=fields)`

If I have a field 'Departments' of type Choice Field, where some items have nothing selected, I get the following (abbreviated) response:

```
{
    items: [
        {
            fields: {
                Id: "some-item-without-selection"
                // No Departments field
            }
        },
        {
            fields: {
                Id: "some-item-with-selection",
                Departments: ["Sales"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect the first item in the response to be like this:

```
{
    items: [
        {
            fields: {
                Id: "some-item-without-selection",
                Departments: [] // Empty array
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We have a situation where a field (column) is optional. When that field is defined, it enables additional functionality for a certain item.

In a situation like this, an empty array (nothing selected in the ChoiceField) is not equivalent to the case where the the field is not defined in the list. We are therefore unable to differentiate the two cases with the current implementation in the Microsoft Graph API.

Side Note 1: We were able to do this with the SharePoint REST API.

Side Note 2: Empty text fields are returned by the api `Title: ""`

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @IvanWilson No, no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is by design for Graph API, as a workaround, you can set a default value for this field.

To access SharePoint list data, I suggest you use SharePoint REST API to achieve it.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SomeList')/items
```

Comment: 1) I don't see how setting a default value can help. This issue occurs when the user de-selects all the choices in SharePoint. 2) I can't use the SharePoint REST API because we are using Azure AD v2 authentication, which the SharePoint REST API doesn't support.

Comment: Open SharePoint site, go to List->List Settings->find the "Departments" column->set default value for this column.

Comment: I know how to set the default value in the list, we are using this already. I'm saying: your suggestion does not solve my problem. A user can decide to un-tick all the choices in the Choice Field for a particular item. Those are the items that trigger this problem.